# PNG-8 upload to S3 hangs

Tags: image, upload

We're having trouble uploading PNG-8s. PNG-24s and JPGs work fine, but after selecting a PNG-8 to upload, the progress bar appears and fills to max in a couple of seconds, but then hangs indefinitely. Sometimes a message appears saying "Upload failed for 'filename.jpg'", sometimes it just hangs with no error message. If we then refresh the page, the image is in the assets list but no thumbnail has been created for it. The PHP error log gets this:

```
[03-May-2017 14:03:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/sitename/webapps/sitename/craft/app/vendor/pixelandtonic/imagine/lib/Imagine/Imagick/Image.php on line 313
```

We could of course make them all PNG-24s but the file size is often way higher.

We're on Craft 2.6.2958, and the assets are on Amazon S3. Any advice on how to diagnose this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To fix that particular error, you'd need to bump your php.ini file's [max_execution_time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) setting to something higher than 30 seconds to allow more time for the request to complete.